# How to bind to the source of the reactive variable?

Tags: svelte

I'm building **editable** and sortable `Table` component, and it uses reactive `$: sorted = sort(rows)` variable. And so text `input`s can't be binded to `rows` directly.

[playground](https://svelte.dev/repl/2c3416a0462b4e42ba2ae24977ecb75b?version=3.38.2)

It's possible to use `onchange` event. But I do like the short and clean `bind` syntax and would like to use `onchange` only where it's really needed.

There are 3 components, `Table`, `Cell` and `StringEdit`. I would like to use `onchange` only between `Table` and `Cell`, as `Table -onchange-> Cell -bind-> StringInput`.

**QUESTION:** I'm not sure, how to convert `bind` directive on `Cell` to `onchange` event?

I'm trying to do it with `$: toOnChange(value)`, but it's not quite working and ending up in the endless loop.

**EXAMPLE**

Table.svelte

```
<script>
  import Cell from "./Cell.svelte"

  let rows = [["Kate", "Bishop"], ["Jim", "Raynor"]]
  
  function sortByName(list) {
    list = [...list]
    return list.sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
  }
  
  $: sorted = sortByName(rows)
</script>

<table>
  {#each sorted as row, i (i)}
    <tr>
      {#each row as cell, j (`${i},${j}`)}
        <Cell value={cell} onChange={(v) => rows[i][j] = v}/>
      {/each}
    </tr>
  {/each}
</table>

<pre style="font-size: 10px;">{JSON.stringify(rows, null, 2)}</pre>
```

Cell.svelte

```
<script>
  import StringEdit from "./StringEdit.svelte"
  
  export let value
    export let onChange
    
  // Converting bind to onChange
  let previous = value
  function toOnChange(v) {
    if (v === previous) return
    previous = v
    onChange(v)
  }
  $: toOnChange(value)
</script>

// if bind:value used it turns into endless loop
<svelte:component this={StringEdit} value={value}/>
```

StringEdit.svelte

```
<script>
  export let value
</script>

<td contenteditable="true" bind:textContent={value}/>
```

P.S. If this approach is wrong and there're better options, please mention it too.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the indices as a key for your elements.

If you sort the `Cell` component is not destroyed but simply get's new data, you can see that very well in the [tutorial on keyed each blocks](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks) (opening your console and inspect the elements).

The same thing as what happens there with the `<span>` happens with your Cells:

**The component is the same, its properties change**

It seems very unlikely to me that you would have data in that form, you table will probably be an array with objects, and if those objects have a key you can use that one, at least instead of `i` (row), the columns are maybe less likely change to change order, there you can stick with the index.